# Maven test does not show the test result

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-junit

I run some Junit tests with Maven but the test result does not show up even the tests pass

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                    <includes>
                        <exclude>**/UiTestRunner.java</exclude>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

     <profile>
            <id>local_dev_chrome</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <appEnv>dev</appEnv>
                                <Selenium_Browser>chrome</Selenium_Browser>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                            <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

I run the test with command `mvn -test -Pxxxx` and the test result is like this:

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Did I miss something in the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

```
<includes>
   <exclude>**/UiTestRunner.java</exclude>
</includes>
```

Here's your problem: surefire will only include tests that match `**/UiTestRunner.java`. The `<exclude>` is just a tag to separate each list item. You could even use `<foo>**/UiTestRunner.java</foo>`.
To not confuse others, please rename includes to excludes (or exclude to include)

Comment: Change exclude to include and it still does not work

Comment: Is UITestRunner a test class or not (should it be included or excluded). Otherwise start be removing all includes/excludes and finetune afterwards.